# Insert Into Table FIleName with Slash Divider

Tags: c#

When a user adds an attachment with a file name that uses a special character like slash divider / I can´t insert it into my database table.

how can I resolved this?

> Filename example: appt w∕ tax.docx

**c# code:**

```
sb.AppendLine("INSERT INTO Attachments(FileName, MimeType, FileSize, [Guid]) VALUES (@FileName, @MimeType, @FileSize, @Guid)");
```

**I have tried this:**

```
string illegal = "\"M\"\\a/ry/ h**ad:>> a\\/:*?\"| li*tt|le|| la\"mb.?";
string regexFileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(string.Format("[{0}]", System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape(regexFileName)));
    illegal = r.Replace(illegal, "");

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = regexFileName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MimeType", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = file.ContentType;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileSize", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = file.ContentLength.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Guid", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = FileNameInFolder.ToString();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Have you tried using double slashes? Or using @ before it...

Comment: I don't really understand why do you process regexFilename before assigning the @filename parameter ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as I am sure you already realise, is that the regex is treating the / as an illegal character and removing it...

"/" cannot be considered part of a valid windows file name, so I would suggest that in preventing you from using it, the code is behaving as it should.